# Setting initial values in ML programming in Stata

Tags: stata

I was trying to examine whether Stata is taking the initial values in the model NormalReg (sample model) that I used from previous `reg`. However, it seems to me by looking at iteration 0 that it is not taking into account my initial values. Any help to fix this issue will be highly appreciated.

```
set seed 123
set obs 1000
gen x = runiform()*2
gen u = rnormal()*5
gen y = 2 + 2*x + u
reg y x


      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =    1000
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,   998) =   52.93
       Model |  1335.32339     1  1335.32339           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |   25177.012   998   25.227467           R-squared     =  0.0504
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0494
       Total |  26512.3354   999  26.5388743           Root MSE      =  5.0227

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |    1.99348   .2740031     7.28   0.000     1.455792    2.531168
       _cons |   2.036442   .3155685     6.45   0.000     1.417188    2.655695
------------------------------------------------------------------------------




cap program drop NormalReg
program define NormalReg
args lnlk xb sigma2
qui replace `lnlk' = -ln(sqrt(`sigma2'*2*_pi)) - ($ML_y-`xb')^2/(2*`sigma2')
end

ml model lf NormalReg (reg: y = x) (sigma2:)
ml init reg:x = `=_b[x]'
ml init reg:_cons = `=_b[_cons]'
ml max,iter(1) trace


 ml max,iter(1) trace

initial:       log likelihood =     -<inf>  (could not be evaluated)
searching for feasible values .+
feasible:      log likelihood =  -28110.03
rescaling entire vector .+.
rescale:       log likelihood = -14623.922
rescaling equations ...+++++.
rescaling equations ....
rescale eq:    log likelihood = -3080.0872
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Iteration 0:
Parameter vector:
        reg:     reg:  sigma2:
          x    _cons    _cons
r1  3.98696        1       32

                                                   log likelihood = -3080.0872
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Iteration 1:
Parameter vector:
         reg:      reg:   sigma2:
           x     _cons     _cons
r1  2.498536  1.773872  24.10726

                                                   log likelihood = -3035.3553
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
convergence not achieved

                                                  Number of obs   =       1000
                                                  Wald chi2(1)    =      86.45
Log likelihood = -3035.3553                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
reg          |
           x |   2.498536   .2687209     9.30   0.000     1.971853     3.02522
       _cons |   1.773872   .3086854     5.75   0.000      1.16886    2.378885
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
sigma2       |
       _cons |   24.10726   1.033172    23.33   0.000     22.08228    26.13224
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: convergence not achieved
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, if you want `ml` to evaluate the likelihood at the specified initial values at iteration 0, you must also supply a value for `sigma2`;. Change the last section of your code to:

```
matrix rmse = e(rmse)
scalar mse = rmse[1,1]^2

ml model lf NormalReg (reg: y = x) (sigma2:)
ml init reg:x = `=_b[x]'
ml init reg:_cons = `=_b[_cons]'
ml init sigma2:_cons = `=scalar(mse)'
ml maximize, trace
```

Note that the ML estimate of sigma^2 will differ from the root mean square error because ML doesn't know about degrees of freedom.  With n = 1,000  sigma2 = (998/1000)*rmse.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like this is very sensitive. You are trusting that the results from the previous regression are still visible at the exact point the `program` is defined. That could be undermined directly or indirectly by several different operations. It's best to treat arguments you want to use as arguments to be fed to your program using the program's options at the point it runs.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will take that into account. But, that doesn't make difference here. Defining the program before and then running reg and then running ml model gives the same answer.